# Strange dispute of an Invalid flag.

Tags: bug, flagging

I always wondered why all of my invalid flags were disputed, and this one is really strange:

Today I saw the first time a reason, well it is about [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359404/probability-of-limsup/359434#359434)
and it was flaged as "not an answer". At least I thought that this flag is wrong at is not "not an answer", that is why I flaged it as an invalid flag.

My flag was disputed with the reason:

> disputed - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

But that was pretty much the same I thought, and I think that the "Invalid flag" is the right one.

Comment: This weird feedback seems to disorient everyone the first time they encounter it (myself included).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Capture the Flag: FAQ on Flagging](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328/capture-the-flag-faq-on-flagging):

> In the case that there **are** disputing votes (where a **10K** user marks a flag **invalid**), the only feedback returned to **all users** from moderator action is **Disputed** (note, not *declined* nor *helpful*; always *disputed*). If the moderator marks the *group of flags* as helpful, that would be the only feedback to the users. If the moderator declines the *group of flags*, in addition to seeing the word "disputed", the users will *all* see the reason for declining the flag. [This is a known bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3983/1543).
>
> To emphasize: if you are a **10K** user and you see your dispute vote return a feedback of "Disputed - a moderator reviewed your flag and found no evidence to support it", most likely this means that the Moderator actually **agrees** with you and declined the original flag. Conversely, if you flag a post and see a feedback of only "Disputed" with no further reason, it means that other users do not agree with your flag, and that the moderators either agree with the flag or acknowledges the fact that there is a disagreement about the flag.